# 500 Internal Server Error Anchor CMS

Tags: html, mysql, anchor-cms

Only index.php seems to work, once any links are clicked, an internal server error shows up. I'm at a complete loss, does anyone have any idea what's happened here? I also can't access the admin page.

http://www.helloarchie.blue

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete     your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@helloarchie.kaye.at and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an     ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .htaccess code. 
I think you have made some changes with the URL's of your site.